# nHibernate - Generate classes from a database?

Tags: nhibernate, orm

I know that you can generate a database from classes and their mappings using nHibernate, but I can't find any good links to do this the other way around.  We have a database that has already been designed, and we are looking at using nHibernate.  It would be nice to use a tool to generate the mappings and classes from the database, and then we could tweak/manipulate them to suit our tastes.

Answer (score 14):

[NHibernate Mapping Generator](http://nmg.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nhibernate with an existing database. It is a matter of writing the mapping files.

I also recommend using Fluent Nhibernate...I started using this after this community recommended it..

Look at subsonic as well if you do not like maintenance of mappings.

Comment: The post clearly states that he wants to avoid writing these mapping files.

Comment: I am recommending Fluent Nhibernate for that reason.

Comment: The OP also states that he wants to generate the *classes*

Comment: Could you explain how Fluent nHibernate avoids generating the mapping files? And whether it does or does not (including a 'how') generate the classes too? That'd be useful for other users who've never touched nHibernate and want to know if it's worth the hassle.